# How to configure/create a Load Balancer that handles users that need to be on the same server

Tags: load-balancing, n-tier-architecture, distributed-system

I have node.js an application running on several instances under a load balancer.

Each instance is homogeneous  (same code running on different servers). Users can be placed on different servers by the load balancer.

The problem is that when 2 users need to interact together, they need to be on the same instance (because they need to communicate together through websockets on the same server). So, I will need to swap the user into another server. I don't know which 2 users are going to interact together, so I don't know before hand which users need to be on the same server.

I haven't seen any configuration in any load balancers to handle this case. I will probably need to create one.

I can also try to use a cache (or any memory accessed by the all the servers), so the users that need to communicate together can do it through the cache, but I'm not sure if that's the best route.

I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: Similar question - [How to distribute (card game table) dealers across servers in a balanced way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57438912/12396017)

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny it's similar but I don't think its solving the same problems

Comment: when user negotiates connection (before establishing websocket connection) instruct  it to use some extra http header field which nginx can use for calculating hash. this way two users will get to the same upstream server. Alternatively full URL or part of websocket URL (some parameter) can be used for hash calculation.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I dont know which users need to be together until after they state that they want to interact together

Comment: then both clients need to re-establish websocket connection with some identical http request parameter for **dumb** load balancer to make decision about picking proper upstream server. If you need to keep websocket connection open then implementation will be much more expensive, like writing your own load balancer with inter-instances communications. So you need to decide whether reestablishment of websocket connection is allowed in your case.